# If R is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

If R is a field, then prove:

1.R[[X]] is a Euclidean domain.

2.R[[X]] is a valuation domain, i.e., that for f,g∈R[[X]], we have f|g or g|f.

Define R[[X]]=∏R. We call R[[X]] the power series ring over R, and call the elements of R[[X]] power series.

For this problem, I can`t find a proper algorithm for b and r in a=bq+r, and by part 2, is that equal to say r=0 for any a and b? How to use the condition that R is a field?

Comment: You use $R$ is a field in order to divide one coefficient by another once you have worked out how division is going to work.

Comment: "Define $R[[X]]=∏R$" That's OK, just as long as you know the multiplication of elements in the ring of formal power series $R[[X]]$ is not the same as that of $∏_{i=1}^\infty R$. I suppose they do have the same underlying set.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

At some point or another, you're going to have to show that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i$ is a unit iff $a_0\neq 0$.

From this, you can deduce that every element in the ring has the form $x^ju$ where $u$ is some unit of $R[[X]]$. After getting this, it's easy to see the divisibility criterion in the second point, and then the right Euclidean function jumps out at you.